# Diseño de Diagrama de Base de Datos Ventas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, diagrama-de-flujo

Necesito formar el mejor diseño de base de datos, en cuanto al movimiento de productos

**Entradas** (Ingreso de Productos al Stock)

- Ajuste de Stock (Incremento)
- Apertura de Stock (Creación del Producto, stock inicial)
- Compras

**Salidas** (salida de Productos al Stock)

- Ajuste de Stock (Decremento)
- Ventas

Diseño de Registros

```
**Movimiento**
 id
 movimiento
 idProducto
 cantidad_before
 cantidad_after
 cantidad
 ref_id_compra (cuando el movimiento sea una compra, guarda el el id de 
 del registro de la compra)
 ref_id_venta(cuando el movimiento sea una venta, guarda el el id de del 
 registro de la venta)
 id_tipo_movimiento


**Tipo_Movimiento**
 id
 movimiento
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es factible realizar esto?, el diseño es a mi criterio , talvez incluyan algunas malas practicas de diseño , pero hasta ahora es lo que e podido diseñar según el requerimiento, quisiera evitar futuros inconvenientes que afecten el flujo y la escalabilidad de mi sistema

**Pregunta**
Como podría volver a diseñar o mejorar este diseño a partir de los requerimientos iniciales? estaré atenta a cualquier sugerencia , gracias

Comment: Para generar el diseño de una base de datos, se necesitan saber las reglas del negocio. No existe un solo diseño de base de datos, ni mejor ni peor. No pusiste las reglas del negocio, solo una especificacion de nombres de tablas, que no sabemos que son. No podemos saber si esta bien o mal eso.

Comment: @gbianchi Hola, gracias por tu sugerencia, inicialmente mencione las reglas de negocio , cuando sera una Entrada y cuando una Salida , a partir de ello yo e diseñado el diagrama , de todas maneras tratare de mejorar la especificación de las reglas de negocio, gracias

Comment: No entiendo cuales son tus reglas de negocio. Si es solo manejo de stock, alcanza con una sola tabla.

Comment: @gbianchi , no abarca solo el manejo de stock, si no todo el flujo , de un sistema de ventas convencional, mi poca experiencia en el tema, es lo que lo hace dificil y ahora pido sugerencias

Comment: Lo que pasa.. es que faltan miles de detalles. Hay manejo de clientes? proveedores? facturas? que tipo de documentos se manejan? tene en cuenta, que de todo eso depende la base de datos que vas a armar. Este tipo de preguntas es dificil de responder, porque dependen de las reglas de negocios y lo que abarque el sistema, y nada de eso esta expuesto aca.

Comment: Es dificil armarte algo completo y que realmente responda la pregunta. Por ejemplo, por que estaria mal tu modelo?

Comment: Lo que si no veo por ningun lado en tu esquema, es donde manejas el stock.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, como mencionaste antes no existe ni mejor ni peor ,asi que yo busco mejorarlo , no considero que este mal tampoco

Comment: @gbianchi por ejemplo lo que consideraria cambiar , seria la logia de poner todos los tipos de movimientos en una sola tabla , y no poner los "ref", talvez seria una mala practica

Comment: Lo que busco es una lluvia de ideas y de ellos sacar lo mejor